# Wireless access point

Tags: wifi

I'm hoping to get some suggestions for possible wireless access point/router models which will allow us to have two separate networks. We run an internal network on 10.x.x.x IP address range where we have shares and other network resources for which we would like to have our regular users access. However, we would also like to offer a separate wireless network for guests which ideally would be on 192.168.x.x, and these users would not be able to see any of the resources sitting on the 10.x.x.x network.

What are some recommendations on single devices that might be able to get the job done? I was looking at the Linksys E4200, and it seems to support what I'm looking to do... any others?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the simplest approach here might be to use two separate wireless access points, on different channels with different SSIDs. Lock down your private one by the usual methods (don't broadcast SSID, use WPA security, etc.). Then do something like a coffee shop hotspot setup on the open one, with a simple password authentication. Then connect the public access point to the DMZ of your regular network and use firewall rules to only allow access to the outside world.

This would probably be a fun project to set up using something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) on some basic cheap home wireless access points. Obviously you might want to invest in some more 'enterprise' equipment, but a proof of concept would be pretty quick and easy to implement.